# Dimension of CSS Bootstrap Grid system

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website for a company and their photographer asks me what dimensions the pictures on the website are.

I work with CSS Bootstrap and grid system like:

`<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/xxxx-1-2.jpg);">
         <a class="image-popup text-center" >
             <div class="prod-title ">
                  <h3 style="height:5%;"> “text"”</h3>
             </div>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>`

So on the server the images had a size of 474 x 698 pixels, but the grid system crops the image a bit?

What size/dimension does the grid system use?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is some css to make your images adopt to a screen of the device. A good practice, that I usually do, is to place this line of code inside my css.

`img {
  max-width: 100%;
}`

Make sure it's at top of your first imported document, so you can override it with out any trouble in case you need some other image width.

PS. This rule should be in bootstrap, so check how you adding bootstrap to your webpage.

Comment: To be clear: the website is done, everything is fine. Just need the dimensions for him.. Indeed, in the bootstrap : .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
  } for example. But how can i suggest the dimensions from adopting width's etc?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a css for this background image.

```
.fh5co-grid{
    background-image: url(images/xxxx-1-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If you want to make sure this code will get the full screen width, make sure your html col-lg-12 is wrapped on a container-fluid.